# Pointing an IP address to a directory in nginx

Tags: nginx

I've got a VPS running Ubuntu and nginx that's currently running a node.js app. I'm trying to develop a static website for someone that I'd like to also host on the server. He doesn't have a domain name sorted yet, so is there a way of getting nginx to point my server's IP address + a modifier to serve up his site?

e.g. 123.456.789.000:9001 --> var/www/mySite

or

123.456.789.000/mySite --> var/www/mySite

Hope this makes sense!

Tom.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
  server_name 123.456.789.000;
  root /var/www/mySite;
  index index.html index.php;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

If you needed any changes tell me, also if you don't know where to put this, create a new file inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available/filename` then symlink it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and run `sudo service nginx reload`

Comment: Thanks a lot that's a great help!

Comment: I tried this on a vm running in cloud azure, and it was not redirecting - any chance that some more setup is needed? could you perhaps explain the line try_files